# dartanalyser produces erros on my enum

Tags: enums, dart

Here a basic code with enum:

```dart
enum Lock {ON, OFF}

void main(){
  var lock = Lock.ON;
  print(lock);

}
```

I can run it, it prints:

```dart
Lock.ON
```

But when I run `dartanalyser` on my code:

```dart
$dartanalyzer enum_demo.dart
Analyzing [enum_demo.dart]...
[error] Expected a method, getter, setter or operator declaration (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 1, col 1)
[error] Unexpected token 'enum' (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 1, col 1)
[error] Expected a method, getter, setter or operator declaration (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 1, col 11)
[error] Unexpected token '{' (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 1, col 11)
[error] Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 1, col 12)
[error] Expected to find ';' (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 1, col 16)
[error] Unexpected token '}' (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 1, col 19)
[error] Expected a method, getter, setter or operator declaration (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 1, col 19)
[warning] Undefined class 'Lock' (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 1, col 6)
[warning] Undefined name 'Lock' (/Users/nicolasfrancois/Documents/dart/enum_demo.dart, line 5, col 13)
8 errors and 2 warnings found.
```

Is it a bug on a wrong code with my enum ?

EDIT:
My dart version is:
`Dart VM version: 1.8.0 (Thu Nov 27 01:01:55 2014) on "macos_x64"`

Comment: What Dart version are you using? (`dart --version`)

Comment: I think, it's the last:
Dart VM version: 1.8.0 (Thu Nov 27 01:01:55 2014) on "macos_x64"

Comment: Dart VM version: 1.9.0-edge.42061 (Tue Dec  2 02:49:13 2014) on "linux_x64". DartEditor doesn't complain, but running `dartanalyzer` from command line does. I think you should create a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new

Comment: issue created:https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21767

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use an undocumented flag:

```
dartanalyzer --enable-enum enum_demo.dart
```

Comment: Nice catch! I think it's a bug anyway because enums should be supported without a flag starting with Dart 1.8.0. Only `await`/`async` is still experimental as far as I know.

Comment: As you have to manually _Enable enums_ in the Editor it looks fine to use a flag. However this flag should be displayed with `dartanalyzer --help`.

Comment: Here is a related issue http://dartbug.com/21415. I remembered reading this comment https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21416#c10 but it seems this applies only to the VM, not to the analyzer.